# PIL throws ValueError: seek of closed file

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

My program throws an exception on line

```
img.save(path)
```

where `img` is a PIL.Image and `path` is a string storing a valid path.

This is the entire exception stack:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/grzes/repos/backend/server.py", line 109, in _run_job
    job.result = lambda_fun(job.progress)
  File "/home/grzes/repos/backend/server.py", line 224, in <lambda>
    return app.jobs_handler.create_job(lambda progress: run_prediction(img, progress))
  File "/home/grzes/repos/backend/server.py", line 251, in run_prediction
    img.save(path)
  File "/home/grzes/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1899, in save
    self.load()
  File "/home/grzes/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PIL/ImageFile.py", line 206, in load
    seek(offset)
  File "/home/grzes/venv/lib/python3.5/tempfile.py", line 886, in seek
    self._file.seek(*args)
ValueError: seek of closed file
```

Any advise on what might be causing this issue?

Comment: How did you actually create `img`?  The traceback indicates that the image had never actually been loaded into memory - this was triggered by trying to do a `.save()` on it, but the original file was no longer open.  You may need to do an explicit `.load()` yourself when the object is created.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**jasonharper**'s suggestion in a comment was actually a solution!

The code comes from a Flask app and the image was opened in these lines:

```
try:
    f = request.files['file']
    if f.filename == '':
        raise KeyError
except KeyError:
    return render_template('index.html', err_mssg="File not included")

try:
    img = Image.open(f)
except OSError:
    return render_template('index.html', err_mssg="File is not a valid image.")
```

Adding `img.load()` after `img = Image.open(f)` solved my issue.

Comment: just had this issue today - thanks! My issue was that images fetched from S3 via `smart_open` worked fine, but I needed this extra `img.load()` to make it work for locally stored images as well. 